How do you remotely debug an Azure cloud service (extended) from Visual Studio?
All of the documentation provides no help e.g.
To attach the debugger to a cloud service (extended support) in Azure
Choose Debug > Attach to Process (or press Ctrl+Alt+P).
Keep connection type at Default.
Enter the connection target, using your IP address and port: {ipaddress}:4026.
Set Attach To to Automatic.
Sign in using the same credentials as remote desktop user.
Select Show process for all users. If you're debugging a worker role, attach to WaWorkerHost.exe; if you're debugging a web role, attach to the w3wp.exe process; for a Web API role, it's WaIISHost.exe.
Set breakpoints (navigate to the line, and press F9), access the site's public URL, and reproduce the scenario to debug.
When I enter the service external ip and port 4024 (or 4026) it can not find nor connect to the service.
I expected the Attach To Process Find command to find and connect to the Azure cloud service for debugging after entering the public ip address of the service and the port 4024 (or 4026). The Find operation says "Found 0 connections". "Enable Remote Debugger for all roles" does not appear as a Publish option.  The .csdef or .cscfg configurations may have something to do with this but I do not know.


"Enable Remote Debugger for all roles" does not appear as a Publish option. The .csdef or .cscfg configurations may have something to do with this but I do not know.


In Visual Studio project, check the below .csdef and .cscfg files which I configured for remote debugging.

ServiceConfiguration.cscfg:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="AzureCloudService1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="7" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
    <Role name="WorkerRole1">
        <Instances count="1" />
        <ConfigurationSettings>
            <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
    </Role>
    <NetworkConfiguration>
        <VirtualNetworkSite name="azurecloudservice1VNet" />
        <AddressAssignments>
            <InstanceAddress roleName="WorkerRole1">
                <Subnets>
                    <Subnet name="WebTier" />
                </Subnets>
            </InstanceAddress>
        </AddressAssignments>
    </NetworkConfiguration>
</ServiceConfiguration>

ServiceDefinition.csdef:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ServiceDefinition name="AzureCloudService1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
    <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="Standard_D1_v2">
        <Endpoints>
            <!-- Add an endpoint for the default msvsmon port (4024 for Visual Studio 2019) -->
            <InputEndpoint name="RemoteDebug" protocol="tcp" port="4024" localPort="4024" />
        </Endpoints>
        <ConfigurationSettings>
            <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString" />
        </ConfigurationSettings>
    </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>


Navigate to the app service in the Azure Portal. Under "Settings" find "Configuration." check "Remote Debugging" is turned on. If this option is not available, it might depend on the type of service you are using (e.g., Web App vs. Cloud Service).


Check that the Azure network security group (NSG) rules allow traffic on the port you specified for debugging (eg, 4024 or 4026). Here I specified 2024
Check the firewall settings on the VM (if applicable) to ensure it allows incoming traffic on the specified port.

Go to Debug tab > Click on Attach process > In Dialog select connection type as webapp/cloud service by that there is connection target paste the site URL.

Select the below processes and click on attach.

By this you will be able to attach the Visual Studio debugger to your Azure cloud service.


My .csdef and .cscfg files are now close to the same as yours however this is a cloud service (extended) not a WebApp.  It compiles and publishes fine but when I try to attach the debugger from the Attach To Process option both the Connection Type and Connection Target are a mystery.  Does the external ip address of the service suffice for the Connection Target e.g. 13.84.225.67:4024? Or is something else required.  All the IAM roles are OK.  In any event I'm still not able to attach the debugger from VS.

I finally found out how to do this.  You have to go to Azure portal and to the cloud service WorkerRole in Roles and Instances and click Connect. This sets  up a remote desktop that where you have to install the Remote Tools and run  use to attach to debugger from VS 1-22 Here's what I had to do to finally be able to remotely debug an Azure cloud service (extended) from Visual Studio 2022:

Sorry, once again. I finally found out how to do this. You have to go to Azure portal and to the cloud service WorkerRole in Roles and Instances and click Connect. This sets up a remote desktop where you have to install the Remote Tools and run msvcmon.exe. Then you have to go to the machine where you  enable RemoteDesktop, enter login and pwd, and Publish (extended). Then go to Debug=> Attach To Process and enter the Connection Target with ip of service and port 4024 (or whatever you selected). You then should be able to read Debug messages and set breakpoints on the cloud service..
